# Show all background in meteor template

Tags: javascript, css, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

I have the following problem with meteor does not take the background either image or color as the following image.

[image: In the image can see that only the color touches me to a certain point of there not for more margin padding etc that you put it does not pass from there.]

[I am following the bootstrap example of the following link](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/)

```
/*css file and html */
```

Edited with new css settings

```css
.container_Admin {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.form-signin {
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.form-signin .form-signin-heading,
.form-signin .checkbox {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.form-signin .checkbox {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.form-signin .form-control {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.form-signin .form-control:focus {
  z-index: 2;
}

.form-signin input[type="email"] {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.form-signin input[type="password"] {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<template name="adminlogin">
    {{> flashMessages}}
  <main class="container_Admin">
      <form class="form-signin" id="login-form">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Bienvenido</h2>
        <input type="email"  id="inputEmail" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br/>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña"><br/>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Iniciar Sesion</button>
      </form>
  </main>
</template>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Meteor? Could you show us your CSS?

Comment: I'm using meteor not a normal html with body and head
I just have <template> </ template> already in several windows it happens to me the same thing only loads me halfway the css is in the link https://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/signin.css
Without the body of that css, same I leave you in the snippet the css